# multi-threading with abstract protected member?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I'm considering an existing multi-threading C# application and noticed some code like

```
public abstract class Task
{
    protected IList<string> action;
```

...

```
    public void Initialize (params)
    ...
```

Several special "Tasks" derive from Task and some Task methods modify "action". So in my idea, this is not thread safe. Am I right ?

Thanks for any help,

Olivier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not right. `action` is an instance field, so each instance of the `Task`-derived class will have its own copy of `action`. It would potentially be a problem only if `action` were `static`.

To clarify, you can have many `Task`-derived objects. Each one of those will work just fine for a single thread. However, you do not want to have multiple threads accessing the same `Task` instance, unless the code that modifies `action` is protected with some kind of synchronization.

Comment: One more question, Abstract class Task call several methods, those ones calling also dozens of others. As long as none is declared static, will each Task-derived class gets a copy of all methods and members ?

Comment: Methods don't matter. As long as none of the fields are static, then all is good. If methods write to static fields, then you have a potential problem.